# How to force caption above a custom text float?

Tags: floats, captions, positioning

I am trying to make a supplementary information text, which I would input to my main document. I want to have the caption above the text and use `caption` package for formatting of the caption (required by the journal). How can I force the caption above the text?

An example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{float} 
\newfloat{sitext}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{sitext}{Text}


\begin{document}
\begin{sitext}
\caption{Mathematical formulae of regression models in subject-specific scalar form.} \label{S:mat:mods}

bla

\begin{equation} 
Y_{ij} = (\beta_{0} + \beta_{x} X_{ij}) + b_{i0} + E_{ij}
\end{equation} 

\end{sitext}
\end{document}
```

I have tried forcing the positioning in several ways (`capt-of` package, `\captionsetup{position=top}` command, for instance), but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these two lines in your preamble:

```
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{sitext}
```

or put

```
\floatstyle{plaintop}
```

before declaring the float `sitext`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{sitext}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{sitext}{Text}

%% put here
%\floatstyle{plaintop}
%\restylefloat{sitext}


\begin{document}
\begin{sitext}
%\caption{Mathematical formulae of regression models in subject-specific scalar form.} \label{S:mat:mods}

bla

\begin{equation}
Y_{ij} = (\beta_{0} + \beta_{x} X_{ij}) + b_{i0} + E_{ij}
\end{equation}
\caption{Mathematical formulae of regression models in subject-specific scalar form.} \label{S:mat:mods}
\end{sitext}
\end{document}
```

I have put the caption below in the code just for demo, but it always stays at the top in the pdf.